# WooCommerce - Check Mailchimp subscribers before allowing coupon

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mailchimp, coupon

I am looking to resolve a puzzle with regards to MailChimp and WooCommerce intergration, our situation is this, we use MailChimp to send out a static coupon, they are static because of our CRM in house. Once a static coupon is sent, people can then use it on our website, however, there is nothing in place to prevent sharing this code with people who haven't signed up, so we would like to make it so when you use a particular coupon, it checks the email address you use on the site against Mailchimp, if you are on the list, the coupon applies, otherwise it does not, I was simply seeking to see if this were possible, if so how?

We're lost on this one so could use the help of the community here, we feel this thread could also become useful to others in the future, appreciate it is specific but could potentially be used in security later on.

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, its worth checking drewm's MailChimp API wrapper, have used it on many WP projects: https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api
You could get the users email from the logged in user data and then use the api wrapper to check 'if exists' in MC

Comment: Hi Rich, Only issue is I want to target non-logged in users....

Comment: Hi Daniel, if the user is not logged in then I cannot see a way around this other than checking for cookie data, however if a user is not on a machine they regularly use for your site and try and use the coupon it would still not work.
Another idea might be to set the coupons on single use only, this would prevent the sharing / profit loss issue.

Comment: Hi Rich, I was wanting to match the email address used when checking out as a guest against the Mailchimp subscribers list, so the computer, IP, etc. wouldn't matter, it would also reject the sharing of the coupon unless the person it has been shared with has also signed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Drewms Mailchimp wrapper](http://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api) or similar you could do the following, don't forget to include your MailChimp API key and list ID.

```
include 'Mailchimp.php';
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
$MailChimp = new MailChimp('your**api***key');

function emailExistsMc($subscriberMail, $list_id){
    global $MailChimp;
    $subscriber_hash = $MailChimp->subscriberHash($subscriberMail);
    $result = $MailChimp->get("lists/$list_id/members/$subscriber_hash");
    if($result['status'] == 'subscribed') {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }

}    

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_themes_guest_email_checker');

    function my_themes_guest_email_checker() {
        global $woocommerce;

        $list_id = <list id here>;

        // Check checkout email address against MC list, if exists proceed
        if ( emailExistsMc($_POST['billing_email'], $list_id) ) {

        } else {
          $woocommerce->add_error( __('This coupon is not valid') );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Rich, Thanks so much for this, this code is bringing up "Fatal error: Class 'DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp' not found" also, can I predefine a coupon for it to check, I only need it to check a single coupon code against Mailchimp...

Comment: Hi Daniel, did you include the Drewm wrapper in your theme or plugin and make sure the include link is the right path?

Comment: Certainly did :-) First line of the code you gave me includes the file which I have put inside the theme directory

Comment: If you are getting that error then there is definitely a path or filename issue issue, make sure they match exactly